# CD Into Mounted Windows Share from Bash

Tags: linux, bash, network-shares, samba, pop-os

I am using Pop_OS (very new to Linux) and trying to access a shared network drive hosted on a Windows machine. I have mounted the drive and when I right-click on it and "open in terminal" I get something to this effect: `user@pop-os:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.1.1,share=share_folder/Member Data$`

My question is: how do I cd into this location from bash?

I have tried: `cd //192.168.1.1/share_folder`, `cd smb://192.168.1.1/share_folder`

Comment: try `$ lsblk` - it should, in my opinion, show you the path to the samba share among all other things.

Comment: Hi @Hannu no unfortunately that just listed a table of information and not a path

Comment: How did you mount exactly? Is `user@pop-os:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.1.1,share=share_folder/Member Data$` the prompt? What does `pwd` print? Does `cd '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.1.1,share=share_folder/Member Data'` work?

Comment: I mounted it using the file GUI. pwd prints `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.1.1,share=share_folder/Member Data` and when I try to cd into it, it says no such file or directory. Thanks.